# Click a button to play sound on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a button play a B-flat scale when clicked. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function PlaySound() {
    alert("hello");
  var bflat = new audio();
  bflat.src = "bflat.mp3";
  document.getElementById(bflat);
  bflat.Play();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="bflat"> </audio>
<button onclick="PlaySound"> B Flat </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not yelling, I'm just frustrated :/

Comment: `onclick="PlaySound"` won't work... that is effectively just a reference to the function. To call a function you need to use `()` so change it to `onclick="PlaySound()"`

Answer (score 5):

Use below code, if the melodies are at some other location.
In Javascript, provide below:

```
<script>
    function PlaySound(melody) {
        alert("On Press of "+melody);
        var path = "path\\to\\melody\\"
        var snd = new Audio(path + melody + ".mp3");
        snd.play();
    }
</script>
```

In HTML body: you can insert

```
<button onclick="PlaySound('melody1')"> button1</button>
<button onclick="PlaySound('melody2')"> button2</button>
```

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Keep it simple (until it works) and try this:

```
<audio id="bflat" src="bflat.mp3"></audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('bflat').play()">Play!</button>
```

Found it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Comment: does it matter where the mp3 file is held?

Comment: @LivyGolini It matters that you don't create a new <audio> element when the button is clicked, because the newly created element may not be able to start playback immediately (especially the first time).

Comment: @LivyGolini: The example in my answer should work, if the MP3 file resides in the same folder as the HTML file. Please test this locally (putting MP3 and HTML file in a directory on your computer and open the HTML file with a browser) before uploading it to a server to avoid other pitfalls. Use the developer output to get more infos about maybe occurring errors (e.g. with Firefox: Take a look at the Tools -> Web Developer menu).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var bflat = new Audio();
bflat.src = "bflat.mp3";
function PlaySound() {
    bflat.play();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<audio id="bflat"> </audio>
<button onclick="PlaySound()"> B Flat </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, try to call PlaySound function using this HTML

```
<button onclick="PlaySound()"> B Flat </button>
```

Keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<p>Click the buttons to play or pause the audio.</p>

<button onclick="playAudio()" type="button">Play Audio</button>
<button onclick="pauseAudio()" type="button">Pause Audio</button> 

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
    x.play(); 
} 

function pauseAudio() { 
    x.pause(); 
} 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```